# Checking internet connection on iOS throws error

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, internet-connection

I have implemented [Reachability](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/IJReachability/blob/master/IJReachability/IJReachability/IJReachability.swift) in my app for checking internet connection. The problem is when I call the function `Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()` it's throwing an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at this line `if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0`

I doubt that the issue is with `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags` or `withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress)` but couldn't debug what exactly the problem is.

**EDIT**

Below is the code I've tried...

```
public class Reachability
{
    public class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably help us solve your problem if you posted the code around your usage of `Reachability`

Comment: @David I've updated my post with the code I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like this:

```
#import "Reachability.h"

- (BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
```